# React hooks useState/setState not working after sorting the array and passing it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I have React app and I am using React hooks:

```
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
```

I am fetching the data and 'companies' is getting filled with data. I also have another button for sorting the data by NetIncome:

```
 const sortByIncome = e => {
    const el = document.getElementById("sort-selectbox");
    const arr = companies.sort((a, b) => (a.NetIncome > b.NetIncome ? -1 : 1));
    console.log(arr);
    setCompanies(arr);
  };
```

The problem is that setCompanies does not re-renders. In the console.log I can see that array is sorted correctly and even if I console.log(companies) I can see that it is also sorted. But noting happens in the interface. Also if I type the same code:

```
const sortByIncome = e => {
    const el = document.getElementById("sort-selectbox");
    const arr = companies.sort((a, b) => (a.NetIncome > b.NetIncome ? -1 : 1));
    console.log(arr);
    setCompanies([]);
  };
```

but pass to setCompanies empty array it immediately works and displays nothing (I have render function that gets companies as param).
So why it is not working with passing arr? Is it because I am passing the same array but just sorted?

Comment: How are you rendering your list? If you're mapping it to a list of JSX elements, do those elements have keys?

Comment: Also, that sort could result in inconsistent results since you aren't returning 0 when both values are same. You can change it to: `companies.sort((a, b) => a.NetIncome - b.NetIncome)`

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla here is how I do it:  const CompaniesResult = array => {
    if (array !== undefined) {
      return array.map((item, index) => {
        return <Company singleCompany={item} key={index} />;
      });
    }
  };

Comment: You shouldn't use index as key! Specially when your items can be reordered. Read: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla What is the best practice for keys in my situation?

Comment: Shouldn't it be setCompanies([...arr])?

Answer (score 12):

Here:

```
    const arr = companies.sort((a, b) => //...
```

`Array.prototype.sort` sorts array *in place*, that is, mutates the original object. The reference doesn't change, and the mutation doesn't get noticed. Do instead

```
    const arr = [...companies].sort((a, b) => //...
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with this tricky part. Your solution worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the hook-variable `companies` inside the function `sortByIncome` will always be the initial value of your hook (`[]`) and will never receive the new value set by using `setCompanies`.

A solution to your problem is to wrap your function `sortByIncome` in a `useCallback` hook with the hook-variable `companies` as a dependency. This will ensure that the function always uses the current value of `companies`.

```
const sortByIncome = React.useCallback(e => {

   // Using `companies` will always result in the current value

}, [companies]);
```

---

[`useCallback` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)